# why i can't extends SimpleSwingGUIApplication?

Tags: scala, user-interface

i need to extends SimpleSwingGUIApplication for my GUI application but i have an error :
not found : type SimpleSwingGUIApplication

there is my code :

import scala.swing._

class GUI extends SimpleSwingGUIApplication{}
thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the standard Scala libraries:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/?search=SimpleSwingGUIApplication

...and if you try Googling it, it's not anywhere.  Spelling error?

Comment: the website is empty !!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what version of Scala and scala-swing you use. In scala-swing 2.0.x it's apparently SimpleSwingApplication, see https://github.com/scala/scala-swing/tree/2.0.x/src/main/scala/scala/swing. Note the "mostly-unsupported" in https://github.com/scala/scala-swing.

Comment: i have downlod the ZIP file scala-swing-2.0.x ,where i put the file now?